# Python - How to avoid calling the grandparent constructor (multiple inheritance)

Tags: python

Classes `B` and `C` inherit from class `A`. Class `D` inherits from both `B` and `C`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A')

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        print('B')

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
        print('C')

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        B.__init__(self)
        C.__init__(self)
        print('D')

d = D()
```

This will output :

```
A
B
A
C
D
```

Is there a way to avoid the double call to the constructor of `A`?

Note : in my real world case, the `__init__` methods from `B` and `C` don't have the same signature, so using super() is not an option (as far as I understand...)

Cheers!

Comment: Do you control B and C? The best thing is to always accept `*args, **kwargs`, extract the parameters each class needs, and pass the rest up to super.

Comment: I do have control on them, and using `*args` and `**kwargs` is a good idea but to be fair, using `super` scares me a bit as I do not have a deep understanding of how it really behaves.

Comment: `super()` doesn't require the method called to have the same signature.

Comment: Then you should read Raymond Hettinger's [Super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? It matters because in Python 2 class `A` would be an old-style class since it's not explicitly derived from `object` — and new-style classes have a different MRO (Method Resolution Order).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know `A` is going to be used in multiple base classes, you can let it detect double initialization on its own.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_initialized'):
            return
        print('A')
        self._initialized = true
```

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a case where super should be used. You can use `*args` and `**kwargs` to control how arguments are dispatched at each level. It's important to note that the order of base classes in your class declaration of `D` controls the order in which super searches through classes looking for the next method. As a result it will also control the order in which positional arguments will be consumed.

eg.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, *, caller):
        print("A.__init__(a={!r}) called by {}".format(a, caller))

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b, *args, caller, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(caller="B", *args, **kwargs )
        print("B.__init__(b={!r}) called by {}".format(b, caller))

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, c, *args, caller, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(caller="C", *args, **kwargs)
        print("C.__init__(c={!r}) called by {}".format(c, caller))

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self, d, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(caller="D", *args, **kwargs)
        print("D.__init__(d={!r}) called by {}".format(d, "user"))

try:
    print("too many arguments")
    D(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5)
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
try:
    print("too few arguments")
    D(a=1, c=3, d=4)
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
print("using keyword args")
D(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
print("using positional args")
D(4, 2, 3, 1) # as B comes before C, B's argument must come before C's
print("using a mix of positional and keyword args")
D(4, 2, a=1, c=3)
```

The output of which is:

```
too many arguments
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'e'
too few arguments
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
using keyword args
A.__init__(a=1) called by C
C.__init__(c=3) called by B
B.__init__(b=2) called by D
D.__init__(d=4) called by user
using positional args
A.__init__(a=1) called by C
C.__init__(c=3) called by B
B.__init__(b=2) called by D
D.__init__(d=4) called by user
using a mix of positional and keyword args
A.__init__(a=1) called by C
C.__init__(c=3) called by B
B.__init__(b=2) called by D
D.__init__(d=4) called by user
```

If you are unsure of the order in which base classes will be searched use `D.mro()`. `mro` stands for method resolution order. It returns a list of classes on which attributes (in our case `__init__`) will be searched.

```
>>> print(D.mro())
[<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, 
        <class 'object'>]
```